# Why is my code infinitely looping in c++. My Code needs to repeatedly prompt the user

Tags: c++

My Code needs to repeatedly prompt the user to input an integer number. When the user no longer wants to continue entering numbers, output the sum of all the positive numbers entered by the user followed by the sum of all the negative numbers entered by the user. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int a, sumPositive, sumNegative; 
    string promptContinue = "\nTo continue enter Y/y\n";
    string promptNum = "\nEnter a numer: "; 
    char response; 
    while (response = 'y' || 'Y') { 
        cout << promptNum; 
        cin >> a; 
        if(a) 
           sumPositive += a; 
        else 
           sumNegative += a; 
        cout<< promptContinue;
    } 
    cout<< "Sum of all the positive numbers is: "<< sumPositive<<endl;
    cout<< "Sum of all the negative humbers is : "<< sumNegative<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `response = 'y' || 'Y'` should be `response == 'y' || response == 'Y'`

Comment: Also, where do you ask for input for `response`?

Comment: BTW, you should initialize your variables, in particular, `sumPositive' and `sumNegative`

Comment: `if (a)` only checks if `a` is non-zero.

Comment: Thats another problem I'm having with my code, when I compile it, it doesn't ask for my prompts, instead it just spits back "Sum of all the positive numbers is (some number).. Is that because i have no line of code where it asks for the input for response?

Comment: You also need to initialize response, depending on where you read input.

Comment: Most likely.  If you try to enter `y` when it asks for a number then that is going to fail and cause an infinite loop.  Why aren't you asking for `response`?

Comment: please dont fix your code after you got comments/answers. The question is for your (possibly broken) code, corrections should go to answers.

Comment: I'm not sure where to ask for the response.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to coding in c++ so I don't know a lot of things

Comment: @Sammy2000 Wouldn't you do it after you use `promptContinue`?

Comment: @NathanOliver what does it mean to initialize a response/ how do I do that? thank you

Comment: @Sammy2000 --  *what does it mean to initialize a response* -- Read your code:  `char response;` -- This could be anything -- a `z`, a `B`, who knows, you don't know, I don't know, no one knows.  Then you do this: `while (response = 'y' || 'Y')` -- even if you wrote this correctly, what happens if `response` started out as a `B`?  That `while` loop would never be entered.  In C++, if you don't give your local variables a value on initialization, it will be any junk lying around at the time.

Comment: I dont know how to initialize response, can you please teach me how please.

Comment: @Amadeus `int`s are default-initialized to `0`. (Required by the spec.) It is not necessary or useful to explicitly initialize them.

Comment: @3Dave, I think ints are only initialized to 0 if you put parentheses after those var names. Otherwise their constructor is never called.

Comment: @Brannon I'm sorry you think that. `Int` has no constructor. This isn't C# or Java. The spec implies that *local* `int`s have a garbage value - whatever was at that location before - while *global* `int`s are default initialized to 0. However, in `main()`, with a variable outside of a loop or a block as is the case here, the variable will always be initialized to 0.

Comment: @3Dave `int`s  are only initialized to zero under special circumstances, none of which seem to apply here. These are bog-standard local variables that will be default initialized and default initialization for an `int` is to do nothing.

Comment: @user4581301 `main()` is a special case. It's not specifically mentioned in the spec, but due to way that a function-scope variable in `main` works, it will be zero'd.

Comment: Just reread your comment @3Dave Yes, there are good odds that the stack will be zeroed when the program starts and decent odds that the values will still be zero by the time the program starts to use them, but there's nothing to prevent the blender action of an optimizing compiler from re-ordering the code such that the `string` constructor doesn't or any of the calls s to `>>` and `<<` don't throw some data on the stack and mess up that assumption.

Comment: @user4581301 Good points. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Brannon This way `int i();`? That's not a default initialized variable but declaration of function `i` with return value `int` and no parameters. ;-) It's similar to instancing of classes with default constructor. `std::string str;` is an empty string as well as `std::string str{};` but `std::string str();` is a function declaration (named `str`) returning a `std::string`. ([Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) While function (definitions) may not be nested, declaration of functions (aka prototyping) is valid in function bodies, in C++ as well as C.

Comment: @Brannon [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92fa249c53ad0040)

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this off the unanswered list:

Your `while` condition is wrong

```
while (response = 'y' || 'Y') {
```

Will always evaluate to `true`. This will cause an infinite loop.

It should be

```
while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y') {
```

However, this will always evaluate to `false` since `response` is not initialized. Fix THAT by changing this from a `while...` to a `do...while` loop. Also, you never retrieve a value for `response`, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    int a, sumPositive, sumNegative; 
    string promptContinue = "\nTo continue enter Y/y\n";
    string promptNum = "\nEnter a numer: "; 
    char response; 
    do {
        cout << promptNum; 
        cin >> a; 
        if(a) 
           sumPositive += a; 
        else 
           sumNegative += a; 
        cout<< promptContinue;
        cin >> response;
    } 
    while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y');

    cout<< "Sum of all the positive numbers is: "<< sumPositive<<endl;
    cout<< "Sum of all the negative humbers is : "<< sumNegative<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There may be other bugs in this sample that I haven't yet noticed.