# while loop and if and else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, sumPositive, sumNegative;

    string promptContinue = "\n To continue enter 'y or Y', and to discontinue and get calculation result enter 'n or N' \n";

    string promptNum = "\nEnter a number : ";

    char response;

    cout << promptContinue;
    cin >> response;

    while (response = 'y'|'Y')
    {
        cout << promptNum;
        cin >> a;

        if(a >= 0 ){

            sumPositive += a;
        }
        else
            sumNegative += a;

        cout << promptContinue;
    }   

    cout << "Sum of all the positive numbers is : " << sumPositive <<endl;
    cout << "Sum of all the positive numbers is : " << sumNegative <<endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

So what the program supposed to is :
- Get user's input until user types 'n or N' to show a sign of stop
- When user type in 'n or N' then the program sum of positive number as well as 
sum of negative numbers.

And what I've been getting

```
Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

this error message, and I'm not sure what the problem is. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275885/why-is-my-code-infinitely-looping-in-c-my-code-needs-to-repeatedly-prompt-the

Comment: `while (response = 'y'|'Y')` -- Explain what this is supposed to do.  Also, assuming you're using good C++ books and materials, have you seen this type of conditional before in an `if` statement?  I bet you haven't.  You should have seen something like `while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y')`

Comment: The error message seems to be a compiler or linker error, nothing to do  with the logic (which needs fixing as others have pointed out).

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
while(response = 'y' | 'Y' ){
```

Should be

```
while(response == 'y' || response == 'Y'){
```

The OR operator in C++ is a double line `||`, a single line `|` is typically used in scripting languages for piping multiple commands.

You were also using an assignment operator in a comparison, `=` instead of `==`, which was rejected by the compiler.

Comment: Downvoted just for "_The OR operator in C++ is a double line ||, a single line `|` is typically used in scripting languages for piping multiple commands._". `|` in C++ is [bitwise OR operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Comment: In addition to the above: "_You were also using an assignment operator in a comparison, = instead of ==, which was rejected by the compiler._" Why do you think, that it was rejected by the compiler? `while (response = 'y'|'Y')` is valid C++. Might not have done the thing, that OP wanted - but it's still valid.