# Unable to debug the errorr probably due to iterator of for-loop with queue and set in CPP

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope

The outer for loop of the last loop should run `umap.size()` number of times but the loop is running for only one time.

It's kind of magic to me. Initially, it gives the expected result, but as I comment (`q.push(b); s.insert(b);`) the two lines present in the last loop and uncomment those two, after this, on compiling and running code the loop runs only one time.

Please help, I am stuck with a day!

I got stuck on leetcode, then I tried on my personal computer but the problem persists. I am running the code on g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> pre = {{1,0},{2,0},{1,2},{3,2},{7,2},{4,3},{5,4},{6,5},{7,6}};
    unordered_map <int, vector<int>> umap;
    for (auto a : pre) {
            umap[a[1]].push_back(a[0]);
    }

    queue<int> q;
    unordered_set <int> s;
    unordered_map <int, int> memo;

    int i;
    for (auto a : umap) {
        cout << a.first << " ";
        if (a.first >= 0) {
            for(auto b : umap[i] ) {
                if (!s.count(b)) {
                    q.push(b);
                    s.insert(b); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Excepted output 6 5 4 3 0 2
actual result 6

Comment: Please try to use a debugger or printf-style debugging. We can help you catch this fish but being able to debug your fish... wait what?

Comment: You have a very suspicious looking variable `i` there.

Comment: I wonder if a.second would be useful.

Comment: It is running for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e32021a84ae9c18

Comment: Keep in mind that is dependent on an uninitialized variable Amadeus (as as already been hinted). UB does sometimes (cough cough) work.

Comment: `for(auto b : umap[i] )`: I cannot see that `i` is assigned nor inited anywhere. That's [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

Comment: @Amadeus Bad luck. U.B. is U.B. and "seems to run fine" is only an especially underhanded kind of U.B. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff oh, an `i` not explicitly initialized. I did not see it on first time. but that seems to be a cloud area. See comments on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275885/why-is-my-code-infinitely-looping-in-c-my-code-needs-to-repeatedly-prompt-the?noredirect=1#comment102919575_58275885 I, particularly, prefer to always initialize them, and I believe it is an UB too

Comment: @Scheff I know that and, that wasn't what I have pointed on my last comment. What I have pointed was that user with high pontuaction use to misunderstand that. Just look at the comments history on that question

Comment: @Amadeus OK, I see. ;-)